populating a matrix by rows
I would like to populate a matrix by row based on a function which gives the seq() of a number seq(1) 1 seq(2) 1 2 and so on
    matrixinp = matrix(data=NA, nrow=6, ncol=6) 

> print(matrixinp) 
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
[1,]   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
[2,]   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
[3,]   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
[4,]   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
[5,]   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
[6,]   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
    
    # display matrix 
    print(matrixinp) 
    
    # fill the elements with some  
    # 90 in a matrix 
    for (i in 1:6){
      aaa<-seq(i)
      print(aaa)
      for(j in 1:6){ 
        matrixinp[j,] = aaa
      } 
    }

This gave me this:
> print(matrixinp)
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
[1,]    1    2    3    1    2    3
[2,]    1    2    3    1    2    3
[3,]    1    2    3    1    2    3
[4,]    1    2    3    1    2    3
[5,]    1    2    3    1    2    3
[6,]    1    2    3    1    2    3

but I would like this:
> print(matrixinp)
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
[1,]    1    NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
[2,]    1    2    NA   NA   NA   NA
[3,]    1    2    3    NA   NA   NA
[4,]    1    2    3    4    NA   NA
[5,]    1    2    3    4    5    NA
[6,]    1    2    3    4    5    6


Do you specifically need to do this with a loop and seq() ? You could make that matrix very easily with R's matrix algebra abilities - multiply a row vector of all 1s by a column vector of 1-6 with matrixinp <- rep(1,6) %*% t(1:6) to get an all-1 column, all-2 column, etc. () and then use matrixinp[upper.tri(matrixinp)] <- NA to set the upper triangle to NA.

@TiredSquirrel Care to post as an answer?

@RuiBarradas - done! Thanks!

I bet a one-liner can solve this, R is a vectorized language.
matrixinp <- matrix(data=NA, nrow=6, ncol=6)
matrixinp[lower.tri(matrixinp, diag = TRUE)] <- rep(1:6, 6:1)

matrixinp
#>      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
#> [1,]    1   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
#> [2,]    1    2   NA   NA   NA   NA
#> [3,]    1    2    3   NA   NA   NA
#> [4,]    1    2    3    4   NA   NA
#> [5,]    1    2    3    4    5   NA
#> [6,]    1    2    3    4    5    6

Created on 2024-09-17 with reprex v2.1.0
Wait, I won the bet.
The trick is to know that R's matrices are column major, therefore with the index matrix lower.tri the values will go the right places.

Very cool!!! But depending on how you count it, that may technically be a two-liner. Here's an (ugly) true one-liner, just to prove that it can be done: matrixinp <- ifelse(lower.tri(matrix(nrow=6,ncol=6),diag=T),rep(1,6) %*% t(1:6),NA)

As a function:
f <- function(n) `dim<-`(rep(rbind(NA, 1:n), rbind(0:(n - 1), n:1)), c(n, n))
f(6)
#>      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
#> [1,]    1   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
#> [2,]    1    2   NA   NA   NA   NA
#> [3,]    1    2    3   NA   NA   NA
#> [4,]    1    2    3    4   NA   NA
#> [5,]    1    2    3    4    5   NA
#> [6,]    1    2    3    4    5    6
f(10)
#>       [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
#>  [1,]    1   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    NA
#>  [2,]    1    2   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    NA
#>  [3,]    1    2    3   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    NA
#>  [4,]    1    2    3    4   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    NA
#>  [5,]    1    2    3    4    5   NA   NA   NA   NA    NA
#>  [6,]    1    2    3    4    5    6   NA   NA   NA    NA
#>  [7,]    1    2    3    4    5    6    7   NA   NA    NA
#>  [8,]    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8   NA    NA
#>  [9,]    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9    NA
#> [10,]    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9    10


This is the fastest for matrices of dim greater than 10 or 12. For smaller dims, TiredSquirrel's seems to be faster than the other solutions.

Makes sense. dim and rep are fast, but it also needs two rbinds. TiredSquirrel's could be sped up with tcrossprod(rep(1,6), 1:6) instead of rep(1,6) %*% t(1:6).

You can try
> replace(m <- diag(1:6) * NA, lower.tri(m, TRUE), rep(1:6, 6:1))
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
[1,]    1   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
[2,]    1    2   NA   NA   NA   NA
[3,]    1    2    3   NA   NA   NA
[4,]    1    2    3    4   NA   NA
[5,]    1    2    3    4    5   NA
[6,]    1    2    3    4    5    6

where

diag(1:6)*NA yields a 6-by-6 matrix of NAs
lower.tri retrieves the lower triangular part of m
replace replaces the values of m as per the mask indicator


Or, if you want row-wise manipulations
> do.call(rbind, lapply(1:6, \(k) `length<-`(seq.int(k), 6)))
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
[1,]    1   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
[2,]    1    2   NA   NA   NA   NA
[3,]    1    2    3   NA   NA   NA
[4,]    1    2    3    4   NA   NA
[5,]    1    2    3    4    5   NA
[6,]    1    2    3    4    5    6

where

`length<-` sets the lengths to the given vector
do.call(rbind, ...) stacks vectors in the list by rows


Please consider adding an explanation of what this code does. These creative one-liners are awesome, but we're dealing with a question from a new user who is learning R and it would be nice if they could learn from some of this. Also I just really want to know what your second example is doing, you've stumped me with how you're using \length<-``

@TiredSquirrel good point! See my comments

Nice!! I did not realize that length could be used with assignment to truncate a vector - thanks for explaining!

1) Create a 6x6 diagonal matrix, fill it with column numbers and then NA out the upper triangle.
library(magrittr)
diag(6) %>% col() %>% { ifelse(row(.) < ., NA, .) }

giving
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
[1,]    1   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
[2,]    1    2   NA   NA   NA   NA
[3,]    1    2    3   NA   NA   NA
[4,]    1    2    3    4   NA   NA
[5,]    1    2    3    4    5   NA
[6,]    1    2    3    4    5    6

2) or with the native pipe:
diag(6) |> col() |> list(x = _) |> with(ifelse(row(x) < x, NA, x))

3) Define cc as a 6x6 matrix with column numbers as above and then use the formula shown.
cc <- col(diag(6))
cc * NA ^ (cc > t(cc))


You can try the following,
# Create an empty 6x6 matrix
matrixinp <- matrix(data=NA, nrow=6, ncol=6)

# Fill the matrix row by row
for (i in 1:6) {
  matrixinp[i, 1:i] <- seq(i)
}

# Display the matrix
print(matrixinp)

Keep the initial creation of the empty matrix with NA values.
Use a single loop that iterates over the rows (1 to 6).
For each row i, we populate only the first i columns with the sequence seq(i).
The rest of the elements in each row remain NA as initially set.
This method makes sure that each row has the sequence up to its row number, and the rest of the parts stay as NA.

Do you specifically need to do this with a loop and seq() ?
You could make that matrix very easily with R's matrix algebra abilities:
# Multiply a row vector of all 1s by a column vector of 1-6
matrixinp <- rep(1,6) %*% t(1:6)

# You have a matrix with an all-1s column, and all-2s column, etc. - now set the upper triangle to NA
matrixinp[upper.tri(matrixinp)] <- NA

But if you want to understand why your loop wasn't working:
    for (i in 1:6){
      aaa<-seq(i)
      print(aaa)
      for(j in 1:6){ 
        matrixinp[j,] = aaa
      } 
    }

When you run seq(4) you get a length-4 vector c(1,2,3,4). You then try to assign it to each row of matrixinp, but rows in that matrix are 6 elements long. That assignment will fail with the error number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length when you get to the 4th iteration of the loop.
Before you get to the 4th iteration, 6 is a multiple of 1, 2, and 3, so for those iterations R fills in the matrix with repeats of your aaa vector:

When i=1, aaa=1, it fills in the matrix rows with c(1,1,1,1,1,1).
When i=2, aaa=c(1,2) it fills in the matrix rows with c(1,2,1,2,1,2).
When i=3, aaa=c(1,2,3), it fills in the matrix rows with c(1,2,3,1,2,3).
When i=4, it stops with an error instead of filling in the matrix.

That's why you got that weird matrix where every row was 1 2 3 1 2 3 - when i=3, the inner loop with j assigned c(1,2,3,1,2,3) to each row of the matrix. Then your loop stopped when it encountered an error at i=4, leaving you with the i=3 version of the matrix.

got it, no wonder I got that error, cheers

For the sake of helping the original question-asker understand, here's the one-liner I wrote in my comment to RuiBarradas:
matrixinp <- ifelse(lower.tri(matrix(nrow=6,ncol=6),diag=T),rep(1,6) %*% t(1:6),NA)

This is messy overly-complicated code from being silly and trying to do it all in one line. You generally shouldn't do something like this in real code, it will make the code difficult for other people to read (or for you to read when you look at it again months later). But it does demonstrate some useful features of R, and playing around with things like this can sometimes help with learning more about R.
This code is best read from the outside in, eg. starting with the outermost function:

ifelse() is a function that checks if its first argument is true - if it is, it returns its second argument, otherwise it returns its third argument.

So ifelse(c(T,F,T,F),'A','B') would return c('A','B','A','B').


The first argument I gave ifelse() was lower.tri(matrix(nrow=6,ncol=6),diag=T), a matrix of TRUE/FALSE values indicating which cells in a 6x6 matrix are in the lower triangle (including the diagonal as "in the lower triangle")
The second argument I gave it was rep(1,6) %*% t(1:6), the matrix algebra from my other answer to your question that creates a matrix with an all-1s column, all-2s column, etc.

This part actually is a good way to make a matrix with a 1-column, 2-column, etc. in R, I wasn't being silly with that. R is optimized for doing matrix algebra very, very quickly, so a matrix algebra solution is often the fastest.


The third argument I gave it was NA

So this code checks for each cell of a 6x6 matrix whether that cell is in the lower triangle. If it is, it grabs a value for that cell from the matrix with an all-1s column, all-2s column, etc. But if it's in the upper triangle, it sets that cell to NA.
And my second one-liner: (!upper.tri(diag(6)) | NA) * (rep(1,6) %*% t(1:6))

Again, this is silly code, don't actually do this
To understand this one, break it into pieces - it is element-wise multiplying two matrices, one created by (!upper.tri(diag(6)) | NA) and one by (rep(1,6) %*% t(1:6))
The matrix on the left one uses R's approach to handling and/or logic to create a matrix that's TRUE on the lower triangle and NA on the upper triangle.

diag(6) creates a 6x6 matrix that has 1s on the diagonals and 0s everywhere else. Its purpose is just to create a 6x6 matrix in a way that's shorter to write than matrix(nrow=6,ncol=6).
!upper.tri(diag(6)) uses upper.tri() on that matrix to create a matrix where the upper triangle (excluding the diagonal) is TRUE and the lower triangle is FALSE. Then it uses ! (the "not" operator) to turn TRUEs into falses and vice versa.

I could also have written lower.tri(diag(6),diag=T) to make that same T/F matrix, but since that requires the diag=T matrix to include the diagonal it's shorter (although less readable) to write !upper.tri(diag(6)) instead.


Finally, the whole left matrix: (!upper.tri(diag(6)) | NA) . I take that T/F matrix and I do a logical "or" with NA. "true or NA" evaluates to "true", while "false or NA" evaluates to NA.


The matrix on the left is the same matrix-algebra based approach I used in my other answers which creates the matrix with an all-1s column, an all-2s column, etc.
When I element-wise multiply the matrix of trues and NAs by the matrix with the all-X columns, R converts the value TRUE to 1 (it would also convert the value FALSE to 0 if there were any FALSEs present). So for the lower half, I multiply 1*1, 1*2, 1*3, etc. For the upper half, I'm multiplying NAs, NA*1, NA*2, etc. which produces NA as a result.


Why would one use ifelse() when full vectorised solutions also spanning not more than one line are available?

Work-in-progress - still trying to come up with better one-liners, this was just the first. What did you have in mind for fully vectorized and also not spanning more than one line?

It's already there: https://stackoverflow.com/a/78993747/20002111

Technically that's two lines, the first line creates the all-NA matrix. ;-) But I do now have a (very ugly) true one-liner that avoids ifelse(): (!upper.tri(diag(6)) | NA) * (rep(1,6) %*% t(1:6))

You cannot argue like so. Perhaps, matrixinp is already there?

The point is not to have an argument, the point is to have fun using R features in creative ways to do this in as few lines as possible. Whether it's 2 lines or 1 doesn't actually matter, the point is just to have fun seeing what you can get R to do.

Here's mine:

# For a `k` between `0` and `n-1`, create a list with `n` vectors
# each containing `k` `NA_integer_` values and `n-k` numbers `i+1`
# then simplify it into a matrix.

n <- 6
matrixinp <- sapply(0:(n-1), \(i) c(rep.int(NA_integer_, i), rep.int(i + 1, n - i)))

matrixinp
#>      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
#> [1,]    1   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
#> [2,]    1    2   NA   NA   NA   NA
#> [3,]    1    2    3   NA   NA   NA
#> [4,]    1    2    3    4   NA   NA
#> [5,]    1    2    3    4    5   NA
#> [6,]    1    2    3    4    5    6

Created on 2024-09-18 with reprex v2.1.0
